# Does this injective function show the set X is countable?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Given a set,

$X=\{n ∈ N :$ n has remainder 2 when divided by 3}

Show that X is countable by finding an injective function from $f: X→\Bbb N$

I found the function,

$f(n) = 3n + 2$

My reasoning is that this is injective because for every value of n in the set X the function gives a value in $\Bbb N$. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any injection is fine. One possibility would be simply the inclusion $X\to\mathbb{N}$, but that would be awfully boring. Another one you could define is $\varphi(n) = \frac{n-2}{3}$. Note that each $n\in X$ is of the form $n=3k+2$, so $\varphi(n) = \frac{3k+2-2}{3} = k\in\mathbb{N}$. It is easy to see that $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{N}$ defined this way is injective.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me and is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

> by finding an injective function from $f : X \to \mathbb{N}$ ... I found the function, $f(n) = 3n + 2$

You have found a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$, not the other way around.

> My reasoning is that this is injective because for every value of $n$ in the set $X$ the function gives a value in $\mathbb{N}$

That is the definition of a function being $X \to \mathbb{N}$. This does not prove that the function is injective.

Comment: That makes sense. So, an injective function $f:X→N$ is simply any function $f(k)=k$ such that $k=3n+2$. Or really any other function such as the one shared by Nelli here $f(n) = (n-2)/3$

Comment: @JohnMacPherson First, I think you mean $f(n) = (n - 2)/3$, as parentheses do make a difference here. Second, you are correct that any function $f : X \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(3n + 2) = n$ is injective. But you are not correct that those are the only injective functions. A function $f : A \to B$ is injective if and only if for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$, if $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ then $a_1 = a_2$. There are infinitely many injective functions $X \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll edit that typo.